# php echo file get content on textarea when press button

Tags: php

Hello i have code like this

```
<html>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" id="get_sock" name="get_sock" class="btn-info">Get Socks5</button>
            <div>
                <textarea name="socks" id="socks" class="form-control" rows="7" placeholder="127.0.0.1:8080"><?php
                    if (isset($_POST['get_sock'])) {
                        $grab = file_get_contents("http://smansara.net/fake/grab.php");
                        echo $grab;
                    }
                    ?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

but i have a problem when i click the button, nothing happens  when i click the button, please review my code sir

Comment: same, nothing happen

Comment: How you can thinks that this button will call your php code without any form or anything else?

Comment: I think that button is not a `submit` type, and it doesn't have any js to assosiate with it, so there won't be any action when you click it, as a result there won't be a `$_POST['get_sock]` to begin with

Comment: and the best solution is?

Comment: @lalithkumar  if you remove if loop then it will show file content on page load and he want on button click.   To Janu Yoga i will suggest create a another php file which echo file content and call that using ajax call on btn click and then add response to this textarea.

Comment: put your code inside <form> tag with method post, change your buttton type to submit, and change $_post to $_POST

Comment: @NMuhammedThamjeed what will be output if button is submit.it will really print file content in text-area or submit that page ?

Comment: Add form before button please check answer below

Comment: This will first submit the page, thus $_POST['get_sock'] will be asigned. Then only your `if (isset($_POST['get_sock']))` will get true.

Answer (score 1):

### Add Form tag Before button then it works correctly

```
<html>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" id="get_sock" name="get_sock" class="btn-info" value="get_sock">
            </form>
            <div>
                <textarea name="socks" id="socks" class="form-control" rows="7" placeholder="127.0.0.1:8080">
                <?php
                    if (isset($_POST['get_sock'])) {
                       $grab = file_get_contents("http://smansara.net/fake/grab.php");
                       print_r($grab);
                    }
                    ?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks ... :) @LongKim

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input type='button'` so that form won't submit if you have.Form is not necessary for ajax call.Try like this:

```
<html>
<div class="col-xs-3">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="button" id="get_sock" name="get_sock" class="btn-info" value='Get Socks5'>
<div>
<textarea name="socks" id="socks" class="form-control" rows="7" placeholder="127.0.0.1:8080"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#get_sock').on('click',function(){
    var contents='<?=nl2br(file_get_contents("http://smansara.net/fake/grab.php"))?>';
    var content = contents.split('</br>').join('\n');
    $('#socks').html(content);
});
 //ajax
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url :'filename.php',//returns the file_get_contents
    success:function(data){
        $('#socks').html(data);
    }
});
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try this? @Janu Yoga

Comment: 103.10.52.83:27666</br>103.10.52.83:29839</br>103.10.52.83:31336</br> the result is like this but i need change </br> to new line \n

Comment: see my updated answer..this will work like charm..you can accept the answer by click the tick mark if helped you @Janu Yoga

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Ajax function on this button click then also need to create an php file which will simply read file content and echo them.

So when you Ajax will called on button click then in response you will get file content the you can add that response to your text area in success.

If you don't know about Ajax then search on internet ,.,here i have given an demo example

```
$(".yourbuttonclass").click(function(){
$.ajax({url: "phpfilename.php", success: function(result){
    $("#textarea_id").html(result);
}});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You should probably wrap your input inside a `form` and then change `button` into `submit` type in order to make the `$_POST['get_sock']` available for your `if` statement. For Example (Somehow can't make the `</form>` tag appears at the end or my snippet)

```
<html>
<form method="post">
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" id="get_sock" name="get_sock" class="btn-info" value="Get Sock">
        <div>
            <textarea name="socks" id="socks" class="form-control" rows="7" placeholder="127.0.0.1:8080"><?php
                if (isset($_post['get_sock'])) {
                    $grab = file_get_contents("http://smansara.net/fake/grab.php");
                    echo $grab;
                }
                ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

$_post is not correct. Use $_POST

```
<html>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" id="get_sock" name="get_sock" class="btn-info">Get Socks5</button>
    <div>
        <textarea name="socks" id="socks" class="form-control" rows="7" placeholder="127.0.0.1:8080">
            <?php if(isset($_POST['get_sock'])){
                $grab = file_get_contents("http://smansara.net/fake/grab.php");
                echo $grab; 
            } ?>
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
   <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="form-group">
         <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" id="get_sock" name="get_sock" class="btn-info" value="get_sock">
        </form>
         <div>
            <?php
               $tareas='<textarea name="socks" id="socks" class="form-control" rows="7" placeholder="127.0.0.1:8080">';
               $tareae='</textarea>';

               (isset($_POST['get_sock']))?$grab=file_get_contents("http://smansara.net/fake/grab.php"):$grab='';
               echo $tareas,$grab,$tareae;?>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</html>
```